# Non-solution to the congruence $ax\equiv 1(mod\ p^k)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number and $k\geq 1$ be an integer. I am just wondering if there is any reference stating that (or reference that proves) if $gcd(a,p^k)=1$ then no integer in the set $S=\{p^0,p^1,\ldots,p^{k-1}\}$ solves the congruence

$$ax\equiv 1(mod\ p^k).$$

Note that the solution to the above congruence is given by $x\equiv a^{-1}(mod\ p^k)$ and there are many known algorithms that solves this congruence. In order to avoid those algorithms, I am trying to look for other possible ways to prove the claim above.

What I had proved so far is for the case where $x=a$. Meaning the statement above holds true for the congruence equation

$$x^2\equiv 1(mod\ p^k)$$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For $x = p^m$ with $m > 0$ we have $p \mid ax$, hence $ax \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$. So the only candidate in $S$ that can work is $p^0 = 1$. And that does indeed solve $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$ if $a \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$.

Comment: Thanks again @Daniel Fischer for your comment. On a second thought, how does $p\mid ax$  implies $ax\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^k}$? Can you explain it further.

Comment: All I can deduce is $ax\equiv 0(\pmod p)$

Comment: You can refer to the multiplicative group modulo $n$ with $n$ an arbitrary positive integer. A positive integer $a<n$ has an inverse modulo $n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,\,n)=1$, and the inverse is unique modulo $n$.

Comment: $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$ means that $p^k$ divides $ax - 1$. Since $p \mid p^k$, that implies $p \mid (ax-1)$. But as $p \nmid \bigl(ax  - (ax - 1)\bigr)$ it then follows that $p \nmid ax$, a fortiori $p \nmid x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I get it now. Thank you so much for the help.